# pandas histogram in matplotlib framwork with date resample

Tags: python, pandas, date, matplotlib, histogram

I have created a dataframe with hourly data and three columns. It look like:

```
                           A       B            C
2017-01-01 00:00:00  14417.5900  15252.8700  15252.8700
2017-01-01 01:00:00   1754.4800  14639.5600  14639.5600
2017-01-01 02:00:00     64.2600     14.7900     14.7900
2017-01-01 03:00:00     50.5789    486.8810    486.8810
2017-01-01 04:00:00      7.2784      8.6431      8.6431
2017-01-01 05:00:00    444.1068     28.7847     28.7847
```

I would like to create a bar histogram where compare at monthly scale the models A,B and C.
As a consequence, I have aggregated the data as:

```
df = df.resample('M').sum()
```

At this point I am stuck. I have tried both pandas features such as

```
df = df.resample('M').sum().hist()
```

However I get three different figures. In addition, I would like to move to matplotlib framework where I can personalize the outputs.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Really really thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with **`kind = 'bar'`**:

```
df.resample('M').sum().plot(kind = 'bar')
```

or [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html)

```
df.resample('M').sum().plot.bar()
```

[image]

We could also use:

```
df.groupby([df.index.month,df.index.year]).sum().plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: Dear all, dear ansev, thanks for you answer. It works. Will it be possible to do that in the matplotlib framework? This will allow me to personalize the plot. Thanks again.

Comment: @diedro : You can access the axis object returned by df plot and use it to personalize the plot.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I manage the problem:

```
 bar_width = 0.2
 x = np.arange(12)

 y1 = df1.loc[:,'A'].values[:]
 y2 = df1.loc[:,'B'].values[:]
 y3 = df1.loc[:,'C'].values[:]

 plt.bar(x,             y1, bar_width,color=colf[0], label=labf[0])
 plt.bar(x+bar_width,   y2, bar_width,color=colf[1], label=labf[1])
 plt.bar(x+2*bar_width, y3, bar_width,color=colf[2], label=labf[2])
```

after that,

```
   x_ticklabels = [r'\textbf{Jan}', r'\textbf{Feb}', r'\textbf{Mar}',r'\textbf{Apr}',
                    r'\textbf{May}', r'\textbf{Jun}', r'\textbf{Jul}',r'\textbf{Ago}',
                    r'\textbf{Sep}', r'\textbf{Oct}', r'\textbf{Nov}',r'\textbf{Dec}']

plt.xticks(x, x_ticklabels, rotation=30)
```

Despite it is not very general, at least in my opinion the result is pretty good.

[image]